# ionic2 microsoft Graph API Get not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

i am adding Microsoft Graph API to an app, and Get is not working. I am not even sure that it send a request. The URL i got was from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

I am able to get authenticated correctly via ADAL, and get a token back. Here is the code:

```
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class EmailRESTService {

data: any;
token = localStorage.getItem("token");


constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
}

load() {

  console.log('Inside EmailREST Promise: ');
  this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
    headers: new Headers ({"Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token})
  }).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.status == 200){
        this.data = data.json();
      }

      if(data.status!= 200){
        console.log('SOmething worng in Subscribe');
      }
    });   
  }
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
console.log('Inside EmailREST Promise: ');
```

but no output after that. I have tried many suggestions/codes from the net without success.

Is this a matter of using ADAL Auth on the wrong API endpoint (Azure Graph API vs Graph API)? i tried using this URL: 
    https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version 
for Azure Graph API without success

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the `aud`  and `scp` claim in the token? You can decode the token from [here](https://jwt.io/) and the claims in the token.

Comment: @FeiXue **"aud":"https://graph.windows.net"** & **"scp": "User.Read"**

Comment: You should write an error handler, the second parameter of subscribe function. Log that error to console. Alternativly you can check the network tab to see why the call is failing

Comment: I think you also need to send Content-Type header

Comment: It looks like you might be mixing and matching AAD Graph and Microsoft Graph - but these are different.  If you are calling Microsoft Graph, then you need to acquire a token that has an audience (`aud`) of `https://graph.microsoft.com`.  The one you have in your comment response is the audience for AAD Graph.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT: i am calling AAD Graph authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net',

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your feedback. i appreciate it.
I managed to get a token for Azure AD graph API and call that library. however, this gives me access to user/group operations, not email and other operations, which i need.
I was just on the phone with Microsoft and they advised me to use MSAL, not ADAL. MSAL javascript package is under preview. And they have no cordova package out yet. Only native devices. I will see how that works for me. Even though i installed the package using npm in my project, and using their tutorial here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js i am still getting some errors on real time  of "can't find variable Msal", i believe this is not an Msal issue per se, but an import issue. **And again, i can't strees this enough" Azure AD graph API" is not the same as "graph API", and the former will only give you access to user operations. So be careful and don't waste your time on it if you are looking to get email functionality**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, you were acquire the token for the Azure AD Graph. However, in the code, you were calling the Microsoft Graph(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`) instead of Azure AD Graph.

To can the user info via Azure AD Graph, you can refer the rest below:

```
GET:https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

Or you can call the Microsoft Graph via get the corresponding token as Dan Kershaw mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I suspected that was the issue before, so i used that, and kept getting 401 unauthorized. i am still getting that. that was partly a cause of my confusion.

Comment: The specs do not use "myorganization" name in the URL. When i use it, i get a 400 malformed error.  i used my organization name as the first part of xxxx.onmicrosoftonline.com, i.e xxxx

Comment: What's the detailed error message about 401 error? It should contain more specific info describe for the error. And `myorganization` also works for the Azure AD Graph as use the tenant name or id. Refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#GetAUser). For the `400` error, please check the request URL contain the `api-version` parameter, this parameter is required to use the Azure AD Graph

Comment: i switched to graph API and getting the "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com" & "scp": "User.Read". When i am trying to get my info through: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ I am getting this error: {code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken",…}
code:"InvalidAuthenticationToken"
innerError
:{request-id: "8a7fe7a2-3314-4d83-b89f-d853c6c7d974", date: "2017-09-20T07:27:21"}
message:"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105"

Comment: I suggest that you track the request using the Fiddler and share the detailed request to help to identity this issue. Or you can share a demo code sample to help us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks Fei. Will do. DO you know what Error: AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance means? I searched without much luck. Thats what i am getting after i switched to graph API.

Comment: The conversation make me confuse. Based on the previews conversation, it seem that you are already get the token successfully. But the latest comment seems that you have the issue acquire the access token. Please correct me if I misunderstood. And for the `InvalidAuthenticationToken`, it seems that you are still using the wrong token. Please double check that audience in the token **sended by the request** is correct.